Create JSON table schema structure
I want to create visualizations of JSON table schemas. These visualizations will be generated on the p5.js canvas. I've written some code for this task, including connections between schemas, dragging functionality, and more. However, when I tested it with different JSON structures, including complex nested ones, I found that my render method didn't work correctly. Here is my render method:
createTable({title, uid, isBase}) {
        return this.handler.addTable(uid,title,isBase)
    }

    createColumn(table, title, isSub = false) {
        return table.addColumn(title, isSub)
    }

    render(data, uid, isBase, ptable = null) {
        if(ptable == null) {
            ptable = this.createTable({
                title: uid,
                isBase,
                uid: uid,
                inside: true,
                parent: uid
            })
        }
        for(let i in data) {
            if (Array.isArray(data[i])) {
                this.render(data[i][0], uid, isBase, ptable);
            } 
            else if(typeof data[i] == 'object') {
                this.createColumn(ptable, data[i] + " (sub)", true);
                Object.keys(data[i]).forEach(key => {
                    this.createColumn(ptable, key);
                    this.render(data[key], uid, isBase, ptable);
                });
            } else {
                console.log(typeof data)
                this.createColumn(ptable, i);
            }
        }
    }

This code didn't work perfectly with this JSON. I took some screenshots to illustrate the problem.

JSON
Schema

For example this JSON
    {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
            {
                "batter":
                    [
                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                        { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                        { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                    ]
            },
        "topping":
            [
                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
            ]
    }

I want to result as this:
"id"
"type"
"name"
"ppu"
"batters (sub table)"
    "batter (sub table)"
        "id"
        "type"
    "topping (sub table)"
        "id"
        "type"

Thanks a lot for any attention...

I want to result as this: how? you didn't show any JSON in the question, and the link you provided has about 8 different JSON examples ... perhaps you did something wrong?

[object Object] shown in your image seems to suggest you're not handling the nesting properly. Can you please make a minimal, reproducible example, so that we can offer better suggestions?

@JaromandaX , I tested example 4 in this link.

@FiddlingAway, I've tested it multiple times, but I'm still unsure how to achieve the desired result. The code I've provided here represents my best attempt at stability. Do you have any suggestions? Perhaps there's a plugin available or a helpful code snippet?

What I meant was - create a runnable stacksnippet, so that we can attempt to diagnose and find where the error is.  Provide the HTML, CSS, Javascript which could be run either here, or on P5 playground. If I try to use your code as provided, it throws a bunch of errors in the P5 editor.

Thanks to everyone. I've completed this task, though it may not be perfect. It worked after some modifications. I've included the code here in case anyone else encounters a similar situation. Happy coding!


function extractFields(obj, parentKey = '') {
        let fields = [];
        for (let key in obj) {
            let currentKey = parentKey ? `${parentKey}.${key}` : key;
            currentKey = currentKey.replace(/^\d+(\.)*/, "")
            if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
                fields.push(currentKey);
                fields = fields.concat(this.extractFields(obj[key], currentKey));
            } else if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
                if (obj[key].length > 0 && typeof obj[key][0] === 'object') {
                    fields.push(currentKey);
                    fields = fields.concat(this.extractFields(obj[key][0], currentKey));
                } else {
                    fields.push(currentKey);
                }
            } else {
                fields.push(currentKey);
            }
        }
        return [...new Set(fields.filter(Boolean))];
    }
    
    console.log(extractFields([{
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
            {
                "batter":
                    [
                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    ]
            },
        "topping":
            [
                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
            ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0002",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Raised",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
            {
                "batter":
                    [
                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" }
                    ]
            },
        "topping":
            [
                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            ]
    }
]))



